# Choosing People For A Committee With Limitations

Tags: combinatorics

> From a group of 8 women and 6 men, a committee consisting of 3 men and 3 women is to be formed.
>   How many different committees are possible if
>   (c) 1 man and 1 woman refuse to serve together?

committee without the "problematic" woman ${6\choose 3}\cdot{7\choose 3}$

committee without the "problematic" man ${5\choose 3}\cdot{8\choose 3}$

Now it seems that I counted twice committes without the "problematic" people so overall it is ${6\choose 3}\cdot{7\choose 3} + {5\choose 3}\cdot{8\choose 3}-{5\choose 3}\cdot{7\choose 3}=910$.

Is there a way to calculate the committees without "over-counting"?

Comment: Note that neither of the "problematic" people refuse to serve on their own. Instead, count the total number of committees and subtract the ones that include **both** of the people who don't wish to work with each other. Correcting for this overcounting is called "inclusion-exclusion" and is completely standard.

Answer (score 4):

There are ${8 \choose 3} \cdot {6 \choose 3}$ committees in total, of which ${7 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 2}$ contain the problematic pair.

This gives ${8 \choose 3} \cdot {6 \choose 3}-{7 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 2}$ committees without the problematic pair.

Comment: why ${7\choose 2}\cdot {5\choose 2}$ count the problematic pair?

Comment: While this corrects the mistake in the question, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @gbox Because if both of the problematic people are included, then you only get to choose 2 more men and 2 more women (of which there are 7 and 5 remaining, respectively).

Comment: @EricTressler my calculation is mistaken?

Comment: @gbox Yes, it is mistaken; this answer is correct. Somehow you have the right numerical answer, but your equation is not true (by a large factor). The lefthand side of your equation is 391650, not 910.

Comment: @gbox you could edit your post to change  $\binom 73 \cdot \binom 53$ to $\binom 73 + \binom 53$

Comment: @WW1 in my calculation?

Comment: I made the edit, it should show up soon, clearly you meant to add instead of multiply